# UPDATE USING PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to update a table using price data from another table however I get an error using an inner join.  I am sure its something very stupid but having spent the best part of my day on this its time to ask for help.

If I do the following SELECT statement to test my inner join syntax works as it should

```
SELECT *
FROM polaracc_osrs_property_field_value
INNER JOIN polaracc_osrs_properties
    ON polaracc_osrs_property_field_value.pro_id = polaracc_osrs_properties.id
WHERE polaracc_osrs_property_field_value.field_id =112
```

However when I then try and run an update statement using the price from one table to populate the 2nd I get the below error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM polaracc_osrs_property_field_value INNER JOIN
>   polaracc_osrs_properties ' at line 3

The syntax used for the update statement is below

```
UPDATE polaracc_osrs_property_field_value 
SET polaracc_osrs_property_field_value.value_integer = polaracc_osrs_properties.price 
FROM polaracc_osrs_property_field_value  
INNER JOIN  polaracc_osrs_properties
    ON polaracc_osrs_property_field_value.pro_id = polaracc_osrs_properties.id
WHERE polaracc_osrs_property_field_value.field_id = 112
```

Answer (score 1):

Your join needs to happen before you set your values like this:

```
UPDATE polaracc_osrs_property_field_value
       INNER JOIN polaracc_osrs_properties
       ON polaracc_osrs_property_field_value.pro_id = polaracc_osrs_properties.id
SET    polaracc_osrs_property_field_value.value_integer = polaracc_osrs_properties.price
WHERE polaracc_osrs_property_field_value.field_id = 112;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Steve I will check this today and get back to you.

Comment: You're welcome Leon, I noticed you're new to Stack Overflow if you feel that the answer is correct and could help others having the same problem please accept it as an answer to indicate to others that it's the correct solution.